# creating a geojson file for itunes

Tags: ios6, geojson

I would like to add to my app the routing app coverage file, I create a geojson file:

```
{"type":
"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[
    [-1.897287,39.035986],
    [-1.862268,39.022384],
    [-1.841154,39.000643],
    [-1.831369,38.980829],
    [-1.862869,38.967084],
    [-1.887503,38.976226],
    [-1.899261,39.007379]
]
}
```

But I got an error:

```
JSON file you uploaded was invalid. Errors : Each set of coordinates provided must be valid : [Ljava.lang.Object;@7de9b790
```

What is my mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Corrected one here:

```
{ "type": "MultiPolygon", 
  "coordinates": [ 
           [[ [-1.897287,39.035986],
    [-1.862268,39.022384],
    [-1.841154,39.000643],
    [-1.831369,38.980829],
    [-1.862869,38.967084],
    [-1.887503,38.976226],
    [-1.899261,39.007379]
    ] ]]
}
```

test it on http://geojsonlint.com/

Comment: finally someone put the sample. I was losing a couple of hours before now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Make sure that the first and last elements are the same (closing the loop). That wasted half an hour of my time.